# new line in TextBox (JavaFX 2.0)

Tags: java, textbox, newline, javafx-2

I'm trying to create `TextBox` with `JavaFX 2.0`.
My source is following:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.setPrefSize(150, 600);
textBox.setText("Hello\n world!");
```

Result is:

[image]

How could I create new line in `TextBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a multilined TextBox is a JavaFX 1.3 feature. In JavaFX 2.0 you have to use a TextArea.

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setPrefRowCount(2);            
textArea.setText("Hello\nworld!");
```

The [JavaFX UI Controls](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/ui_controls/overview.htm#BABJACHC) tutorial does not mention the TextArea control. Maybe they missed something. As you can see in this [JavaFX 1.3 TextBox](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/UIControls/textBox.html) tutorial the TextBox had a 'multiline' and a 'lines' property. JavaFX 1.3 did not have a TextArea.