# How to add line breaks to prompt text in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextArea that has some prompt text that I want to be split onto a few different lines, however, line breaks don't work in prompt text for some reason.

Code:

```
TextArea paragraph = new TextArea();
paragraph.setWrapText(true);
paragraph.setPromptText(
    "Stuff done today:\n"
    + "\n"
    + "- Went to the grocery store\n"
    + "- Ate some cookies\n"
    + "- Watched a tv show"
);
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the text does not line break properly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723506/new-line-in-textbox-javafx-2-0/6820500

Comment: @ajkush That's regular text not prompt text. Strangely enough, line breaks work with regular text but not with prompt text.

Comment: In your example code, I assume you meant `setPromptText` and not `setText`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prompt is internally shown by a node of type Text which can handle line breaks. So the interesting question is why don't they show? Reason is revealed by looking at the promptText property: it is silently replacing all `\n` with empty strings:

```
private StringProperty promptText = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "promptText", "") {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
        // Strip out newlines
        String txt = get();
        if (txt != null && txt.contains("\n")) {
            txt = txt.replace("\n", "");
            set(txt);
        }
    }
};
```

A way around (not sure if it is working on all platforms - does on my win) is to use the `\r` instead:

```
paragraph.setPromptText(
    "Stuff done today:\r"
    + "\r"
    + "- Went to the grocery store\r"
    + "- Ate some cookies\r"
    + "- Watched a tv show"
);
```

Comment: not working with me

Comment: Using \r works also for me on Ubuntu.